# PyQt auto-space qlineedit characters

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlineedit

Am having a qlineedit where a user types a verification code. I want to be able to space these numbers automatically every after 5 characters just like it is when activating windows where dashes are  automatically added.
For example

```
12345 67890 12345 67890
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of digits is fixed the best option is to use [`setInputMask()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setInputMask), in your case:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = QLineEdit()
    le.setInputMask(("ddddd "*4)[:-1])
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the case that the number of lines is variable it is better to use the [`textChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signal and to add it whenever it is necessary, besides so that it is possible to write we establish a QValidator as I show next.

```
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def  __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("(\\d+)")))

    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        if len(text) % 6 == 5:
            self.setText(self.text()+" ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = LineEdit()
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Very nice. I don't understand the `self.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("(\\d+)")))`part though.

Comment: The idea is to validate the input so that it only accepts the digits, for it Qt offers 3 validators by default which are QDoubleValidator, QIntValidator and QRegExpValidator, in this case although there are numbers within the text, the full text is not a number so is better valued character by character, for that we use QRegExpValidator, this uses a regular expression for validation (these expressions have a particular syntax but in it it indicates that the digits are set with dy to indicate that it is expected that there is more than one character se usa +). :P