# Auto format byte array in QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit

I want that my QLineEdit to insert a space after every two characters, I want his because in that QLineEdit I will insert on hexadecimal character.
I tried the code from below from this post: [PyQt auto-space qlineedit characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069642/pyqt-auto-space-qlineedit-characters) and it's work very well but when I want to delete a characters it work only when occurs the last space, and then I can't delete anything.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication

class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def  __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("(\\d+)")))

    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        if len(text) % 6 == 5:
            self.setText(self.text()+" ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = LineEdit()
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Uhm, your regex doesn't seem to work for hexadecimal characters... Anyway, if you want to only accept hexadecimals, you could use [`setInputMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) with the "H" mask. You can put an arbitrary number of "HH " up to the possible limit of the input; for example, if you want only 8 pairs: `self.setInputMask(' '.join('HH' for i in range(8)))` (there's a space between the first two quotes, in case you see the line broken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use this class multiple times I think the best way is to inherit a custom class from QLineEdit (like you already did) but add setInputMask() to it.

Try this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication
import sys

class HexLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def  __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setInputMask("HH HH HH HH")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = HexLineEdit()
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```